# USERFORM Function Error

Tags: excel, vba, function, userform

I've been trying to create a simple USERFORM function. My requirement is to basically compute add, multiply, divide, and minus mathematical functions. However I had difficulties, when I run ADD function, say I add 5 plus 5 then it comes out 55 instead of 10.

Example as below

```
A Value = 5
B Value = 5
Result  = 55
```

It shouldn't be 55.

Comment: we can't tell you what is wrong if you do not show your code. Only as a guess: you use string vars instead of numeric vars and try something like A+B

Comment: Private Sub add_btn_Click()

    Jawapan = Ainput + Binput
    
End Sub

Comment: and what is Ainput and Binput? Try something like Jawapan = CDbl(Ainput) + CDbl(Binput)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add values that are stored as string, you should use a conversion function like `CDbl`, and your code would be :

```
Private Sub add_btn_Click() 
    Jawapan = CDbl(Ainput) + CDbl(Binput) 
End Sub
```

And to concatenate text in VBA, you should use `&` and not `+`

So your code should be :

```
Private Sub add_btn_Click() 
    Jawapan = Ainput & Binput 
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry there, I'm a bit rushing at posting questions. My intention was to make 5 plus 5 equals 10. Instead I end up 5 plus 5 equals 55. So I was thinking what went wrong here?

Comment: Thank you very much. That Worked! Thank you.